# How to determine the cause of state update in svelte two way binding?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, two-way-binding, svelte-store

There's a variable `x` bound to an input element.

```
export let x;

$: doSomethingIfxWasUpdatedExternally();

<input bind:value={x} />
```

How to know whether the state `x` was updated externally or by the user typing in the input?

Comment: What exactly is your *actual* goal here?

Comment: @H.B. I want to reflect the content of monaco editor into a reactive variable `editorContent`. So, you can externally update editor's contents by just reassigning the `editorContent` and when the user types in the editor, `editorContent` is immediately updated to reflect that.  You can detect the change by passing a cb to `editor.onDidChangeModelContent()` and you can set its content by using: `editor.setValue()` But this is causing an infinite loop and ui freezes.

Comment: You should not get a loop if the value does not get changed along the way somehow.

Comment: @H.B. You're right. I looked into it and found an intermediate formatting step. Couldn't see it before because wasn't really looking for it. Thanks a bunch! for pointing me in the right direction. I now have a better understanding of svelte. **reassignment doesn't cause reactivity, value change causes it**

Comment: You are welcome. One more note on that: Reactivity is conservative to better support nested updates, so only for primitive types, equality will stop change notifications from being propagated. So even if the same *object* is reassigned, this can cause cascading updates.

Comment: @H.B. Got it. That's a really important nuance. It has caused me some good amount of headaches in the past. I have plans to make all state objects immutable in my codebase. Then use the `<svelte:option immutable />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. Instead of the binding, you could pass in the value in and use the `input` event to get it out.

But even then, reactive statements can and will fire fairly unpredictably, you should not rely on when and how often they run. They should define invariants not run transactional logic.

---

Here would be a convoluted set-up that sort of works, but I definitely would not recommend using this:

```html
<script>
    import { afterUpdate } from 'svelte';

    export let value;

    let updating = false;
    // Function hides `updating` from reactive statement
    const isUpdating = () => updating;
    // Reset flag after reactive statements
    afterUpdate(() => updating = false);
    
    $: if (isUpdating() == false) {
        console.log('Value changed externally:', value);
    }

    function onInput(e) {
        updating = true;
        value = e.target.value;
        console.log('Value changed internally:', e.target.value);
    }
</script>

<input {value} on:input={onInput} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c6ae9a793a6c4e6fb9afefc8d9fb209e?version=3.51.0)